# Why the script do not print the text? Problems with Tkinter

Tags: python, class, object, tkinter

I have two scripts, the first script consist in a tkinter's window with a button "Cerca" that call a method in a second script that open a second tkinter's window that show a keyboard on screen.
The problem is that the text do not show in Entry model even thought if the variable exp is evaluated.

Here the first script (main.py):

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
from settings import Settings
from buttons.cerca import Cerca


class TIICP():
    def event_test():
        return messagebox.showinfo('Test', 'This is a test!')

    def cerca():
        Cerca.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.title(Settings.get_setting_data("title"))
    window_width = Settings.get_setting_data("width")
    window_height = Settings.get_setting_data("height")
    screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()
    center_x = int(screen_width / 2 - window_width / 2)
    center_y = int(screen_height / 2 - window_height / 2)
    window.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')
    window.configure(bg='black')

    # Esplora
    esplora_button = tkinter.Button(
        window,
        text='Esplora',
        command=TIICP.event_test
    )
    esplora_button.pack(
        ipadx=5,
        ipady=5,
        expand=True
    )

    # Cerca
    cerca_button = tkinter.Button(
        window,
        text='Cerca',
        command=TIICP.cerca
    )
    cerca_button.pack(
        ipadx=5,
        ipady=5,
        expand=True
    )

    # Radio
    radio_button = tkinter.Button(
        window,
        text='Radio',
        command=TIICP.event_test
    )
    radio_button.pack(
        ipadx=5,
        ipady=5,
        expand=True
    )

    window.mainloop()
```

Here the second script (cerca.py):

```
import tkinter
from settings import Settings
from tkinter import ttk

exp = " "

class Cerca:
    def start():
        cerca_window = tkinter.Tk()
        cerca_window.title(Settings.get_setting_data("title"))

        def press(num):
            global exp
            exp = exp + str(num)
            equation.set(exp)

        def clear():
            global exp
            exp = " "
            equation.set(exp)

        def action():
            exp = " Next Line : "
            equation.set(exp)

        def Tab():
            exp = " TAB : "
            equation.set(exp)

        window_width = Settings.get_setting_data("width")
        window_height = Settings.get_setting_data("height")
        screen_width = cerca_window.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = cerca_window.winfo_screenheight()
        center_x = int(screen_width / 2 - window_width / 2)
        center_y = int(screen_height / 2 - window_height / 2)
        cerca_window.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')
        cerca_window.configure(bg='green')

        equation = tkinter.StringVar()
        Dis_entry = ttk.Entry(cerca_window, state='readonly', textvariable=equation)
        Dis_entry.grid(rowspan=1, columnspan=100, ipadx=1000, ipady=20)

        q = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='Q', width=6, command=lambda: press('Q'))
        q.grid(row=1, column=0, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        w = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='W', width=6, command=lambda: press('W'))
        w.grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        E = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='E', width=6, command=lambda: press('E'))
        E.grid(row=1, column=2, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        R = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='R', width=6, command=lambda: press('R'))
        R.grid(row=1, column=3, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        T = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='T', width=6, command=lambda: press('T'))
        T.grid(row=1, column=4, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        Y = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='Y', width=6, command=lambda: press('Y'))
        Y.grid(row=1, column=5, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        U = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='U', width=6, command=lambda: press('U'))
        U.grid(row=1, column=6, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        I = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='I', width=6, command=lambda: press('I'))
        I.grid(row=1, column=7, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        O = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='O', width=6, command=lambda: press('O'))
        O.grid(row=1, column=8, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        P = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='P', width=6, command=lambda: press('P'))
        P.grid(row=1, column=9, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        cur = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='{', width=6, command=lambda: press('{'))
        cur.grid(row=1, column=10, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        cur_c = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='}', width=6, command=lambda: press('}'))
        cur_c.grid(row=1, column=11, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        back_slash = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='\\', width=6, command=lambda: press('\\'))
        back_slash.grid(row=1, column=12, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        clear = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='Clear', width=6, command=clear)
        clear.grid(row=1, column=13, ipadx=20, ipady=10)

        # Second Line Button

        A = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='A', width=6, command=lambda: press('A'))
        A.grid(row=2, column=0, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        S = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='S', width=6, command=lambda: press('S'))
        S.grid(row=2, column=1, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        D = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='D', width=6, command=lambda: press('D'))
        D.grid(row=2, column=2, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        F = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='F', width=6, command=lambda: press('F'))
        F.grid(row=2, column=3, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        G = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='G', width=6, command=lambda: press('G'))
        G.grid(row=2, column=4, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        H = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='H', width=6, command=lambda: press('H'))
        H.grid(row=2, column=5, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        J = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='J', width=6, command=lambda: press('J'))
        J.grid(row=2, column=6, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        K = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='K', width=6, command=lambda: press('K'))
        K.grid(row=2, column=7, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        L = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='L', width=6, command=lambda: press('L'))
        L.grid(row=2, column=8, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        semi_co = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text=';', width=6, command=lambda: press(';'))
        semi_co.grid(row=2, column=9, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        d_colon = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='"', width=6, command=lambda: press('"'))
        d_colon.grid(row=2, column=10, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        enter = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='Enter', width=6, command=action)
        enter.grid(row=2, columnspan=75, ipadx=85, ipady=10)

        # third line Button

        Z = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='Z', width=6, command=lambda: press('Z'))
        Z.grid(row=3, column=0, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        X = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='X', width=6, command=lambda: press('X'))
        X.grid(row=3, column=1, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        C = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='C', width=6, command=lambda: press('C'))
        C.grid(row=3, column=2, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        V = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='V', width=6, command=lambda: press('V'))
        V.grid(row=3, column=3, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        B = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='B', width=6, command=lambda: press('B'))
        B.grid(row=3, column=4, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        N = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='N', width=6, command=lambda: press('N'))
        N.grid(row=3, column=5, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        M = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='M', width=6, command=lambda: press('M'))
        M.grid(row=3, column=6, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        left = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='<', width=6, command=lambda: press('<'))
        left.grid(row=3, column=7, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        right = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='>', width=6, command=lambda: press('>'))
        right.grid(row=3, column=8, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        slas = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='/', width=6, command=lambda: press('/'))
        slas.grid(row=3, column=9, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        q_mark = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='?', width=6, command=lambda: press('?'))
        q_mark.grid(row=3, column=10, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        coma = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text=',', width=6, command=lambda: press(','))
        coma.grid(row=3, column=11, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        dot = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='.', width=6, command=lambda: press('.'))
        dot.grid(row=3, column=12, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        shift = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='Shift', width=6, command=lambda: press('Shift'))
        shift.grid(row=3, column=13, ipadx=20, ipady=10)

        # Fourth Line Button

        ctrl = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='Ctrl', width=6, command=lambda: press('Ctrl'))
        ctrl.grid(row=4, column=0, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        Fn = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='Fn', width=6, command=lambda: press('Fn'))
        Fn.grid(row=4, column=1, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        window = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='Window', width=6, command=lambda: press('Window'))
        window.grid(row=4, column=2, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        Alt = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='Alt', width=6, command=lambda: press('Alt'))
        Alt.grid(row=4, column=3, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        space = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='Space', width=6, command=lambda: press(' '))
        space.grid(row=4, columnspan=14, ipadx=160, ipady=10)

        Alt_gr = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='Alt Gr', width=6, command=lambda: press('Alt Gr'))
        Alt_gr.grid(row=4, column=10, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        open_b = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='(', width=6, command=lambda: press('('))
        open_b.grid(row=4, column=11, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        close_b = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text=')', width=6, command=lambda: press(')'))
        close_b.grid(row=4, column=12, ipadx=6, ipady=10)

        tap = ttk.Button(cerca_window, text='Tab', width=6, command=Tab)
        tap.grid(row=4, column=13, ipadx=20, ipady=10)


        cerca_window.mainloop()
```

Could you please help me with this problem?
Thanks in advice.

Comment: Most probably same issue as this question ["Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged)

Comment: Can you advise me a library or framework that supports multiple instances?

Comment: Try using `tkinter.Toplevel()` instead of `tkinter.Tk()` inside `Cerca`.

Answer (score 0):

I used `tkinter.Toplevel()` instead of `tkinter.Tk()` inside Cerca.